# SvgXml inside react native storybook for web

Tags: react-native, storybook, react-native-web

I'm implementing StoryBook in a react-native project and running it on the web and mobile with that design:

https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-react-native-web

https://github.com/dannyhw/addon_react_native_web_example.

https://github.com/dannyhw/react-native-template-storybook/tree/main/template

I tried to show on the web a component that uses 'SvgXml':

```
import { SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';

export const SignatureSvgs3: ComponentStory<any> = args => <SvgXml xml={xmlData} />;
```

My main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/stories/**/*.stories.?(ts|tsx|js|jsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-react-native-web',
      options: {
        modulesToTranspile: ['react-native-reanimated'],
        babelPlugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
};
```

But I got an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayName')"

[image]

I tried to follow this: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6188

solution without any luck.

I can see that on mobile but not on the web

If someone handle it before I will be more than happy for the help

**Edit for Danny:**
I took your repo https://github.com/dannyhw/addon_react_native_web_example
and changed FavoriteIcon.stories.tsx to:

```
import React, {ReactElement} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {SvgXml} from 'react-native-svg';


const wirelessNetworkXML = (
  height: number,
  width: number,
) => `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="${width}" height="${height}" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="24" height="24" transform="translate(0 0.318359)" fill="transparent" fill-opacity="0.01" />
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3.75 18.3184H5.25V22.0684H3.75V18.3184ZM9 22.0684H10.5V13.0684H9V22.0684ZM14.25 22.0684H15.75V7.81836H14.25V22.0684ZM19.5 2.56836V22.0684H21V2.56836H19.5Z" />
</svg>`;

export const wirelessNetworkIcon = (
  fillColor = 'grey',
  height = 24,
  width = 24,
): ReactElement => (
  <SvgXml
    fill={fillColor}
    xml={wirelessNetworkXML(height, width)}
    style={{height, width}}
  />
);

export const wirelessNetwork = () => (
  <View>
    {wirelessNetworkIcon()}
  </View>
);

export default {
  title: 'components/svgs/general',
};
```

Comment: Hey! Maintainer off addon-react-native-web here if you are able to share the repository I would happily debug it for you. I have react-native-svg working in my examples so its weird to see this. Is it only the xml component that doesn't work?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response @Danny, yea when I tried to use SVG it works but when I tried SvgXml it doesn't work. the problem is that all my SVG's in the code use SvgXml and it could take time to change all the code to the regular SVG

Comment: @Danny I updated the post for you

Comment: hey sorry for not getting back to you, did you have any luck solving it? I still have it mind to check this. However I wanted to mention that there is a alternative workaround which you can try. If you alias the react-native-svg package to react-native-svg-web then it might work, can you try it? The rnw addon has a configuration setting for aliasing packages.

Comment: Hi @Danny, my solution was to work with <Svg> and not <SvgXml> component, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use this package https://github.com/shamilovtim/react-native-svgxml-web and importing like this:

```js
import {SvgXml} from 'react-native-svgxml-web';
// ...rest of the code
<SvgXml width={width || size} height={height || size} xml={icon} />
```

and for me that works fine :D